# I have very complex JSON response coming from server. I need to insert in local database using Room and need to use auto synchronisation

Tags: android, android-room

Thanks in Advance. This is the response what i am getting. I need to insert this data to local database using room library and need to use auto synchronization in android.

I need to create a local database with this data . I am not clear how to save list and List in android.

```
  {"email": "abc@gmail.com",
       "createdOn": "1530344810442",
       "childname": "kid1",
       "statuscode": "Open",
       "programs": ["a","b"],
       "labels": [
           "5b360152a987ba31b26ced9d",
           "5b360152a987ba31b26ced98"
       ],
       "enquiriedPrograms": [
           "FIRST",
           "Daycare"
       ],
       "details": "Rosy [11:53 a.m. 10 Mar 2018 ] - Interested to join in next year",
       "dateofenquiry": "1520682660000",
       "followup": "1552132380000",
       "channel": "Parent referral",
       "academicYear": "2019-20",
       "childDOB": "959668410000",
       "country": "India",
       "countryCode": "91",
       "country_name_code": "IN",
       "secodaryContact": "99563959718",
       "secodaryCountry": "India",
       "secodaryCountryCode": "91",
       "secodarycountry_name_code": "IN",
       "priority": "0",
       "_id": "5b37356afa4f6c15a0474d08",
       "parentname": "parent",
       "mobile": "96542372812",
       "schoolid": "59df41728832621654417350",
       "__v": 0,
       "labelNames": [
           {
               "_id": "5b360152a987ba31b26ced9d",
               "name": "Add",
               "colourCode": "#FFFF00"
           },
           {
               "_id": "5b360152a987ba31b26ced98",
               "name": "sub",
               "colourCode": "#7FB3D5"
           }
       ]
   }
```

Comment: what exactly is a problem? You can't just ask for entire code

Comment: With `Room` library, it's simple to insert list. 
`@Insert public void insertObjects(List<Object> obj);`

Comment: This should help http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/